# How Insert Video with JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I Have this code:

```
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/mykey.js"></script>
<div id="mediaplayer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
file : '<?php echo $link_it; ?>' ,
width: 640 ,
height : 480
});
</script>
```

i have the link of the url in PHP...
So, i use this code with a file.mp4 , but it doesn't work and tells me: File Not Found

I see in source of other website, this code:

```
<span class="jwmain"><span class="jwvideo">
    <video src="<?php echo $link_en; ?>"></video></span>
            </span>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var playad          = false;
                var bannerad        = true;
                var ad_vid          = "";
                var width           = "640";
                var height          = "480";
                var swf             = "jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf";
                var vid             = new Array();
                var image           = new Array();
                var i               = new Array();
                vid[0]          = "<?php echo $link_en; ?>"; // i insert php
                image[0]        = "img.png";
                i[0]            = 0;
                loadplayer(0);

            </script>
```

And it doesn't work, i wrong how i use it probably... How i can to see my file .mp4? There are other player ?  so, i use JW6.9

Comment: is your `$link_en` correct path to the video?

Comment: yes, because in JS it prints the url of video : http://prntscr.com/41w43e

Comment: and the `jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf` exist? is this path right too?

Comment: You can use html 5 video tag if you like

Comment: Could you provide link where you run this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You print php code instead of execute it,
please replace

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
file : '<?php echo $link_it; ?>' ,
width: 640 ,
height : 480
});
</script>
```

with:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
file : <?php echo "'". $link_it ."'" ; ?>' ,
width: 640 ,
height : 480
});
</script>
```

Comment: share the link to the page, not to video.

Comment: now the player configuration is OK. But the video probably damaged. Try to re-encode with handbrake

Comment: but with HTML5 how i can do it?

Comment: You need to understand that your problem is http://goo.gl/D3fX9w doesn't work. you can't play this file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Under this line of code:

```
file : '<?php echo $link_it; ?>' ,
```

Add this line:

```
type: 'mp4',
```

Does that help?

Comment: I tested with this configuration with no success, I think the access to this video available to specific domains.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe if the original poster can provide a link, that would help, then.